# java 8 supported web service frameworks

Tags: java, web-services, java-8

What are the java 8  features supported web service frame works.

I tried with axis2 latest version, but it shows the below error,

```
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: Error looking for paramter names in bytecode: unexpected bytes in file
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:441)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:232)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:154)
```

Comment: have a look at cxf (http://cxf.apache.org)